# jQuery how to get element by id and remove the element?

Tags: jquery

How to get an element by id from this form and remove it?

```
<form class="mainForm" name="eform" id="eform" action="#" method="post">    
    <input type="submit" id="savebutton" value="Save" class="greenBtn" />
    <input type="button" id="deletebutton" value="Delete" class="redBtn" />
    <input type="button" id="dupbutton" value="Duplicate" class="blueBtn" />
    <input type="reset" id="resetbutton" value="Reset" class="greyishBtn" />
</form>
```

Comment: This is a **very** basic question. Sufficient information is provided in the always-useful [jQuery API documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/) I suggest you start there.

Comment: This is jQuery 101. Look at the jQuery documentation at http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
$("#idOfItem").remove();
```

So for example, to remove the Save button, do:

```
$("#savebutton").remove();
```

Comment: Just vote to close questions like these.

Comment: @MattBall Yeah I've voted to close, but I was feeling helpful so I answered it too :)

Comment: yes but how I say from this form delete this elemId?

Answer (score 1):

jquery uses css selectors, so after # enter your element's Id then call remove function!

```
$("#yourid").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do :

```
 $("#elemId").remove();
```

See : http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: yes but how I say from this form delete this elemId?

Comment: The id must be unique. You don't need to specify that is nested in the form. but if you insist you can do `$("#formId #elemId").remove();`